# Changing where PHP logs syntax errors

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

How would I go about changing where PHP logs it's syntax errors? I've got multiple people working on the same server, and I want to be able to send my own logs to a custom file so that I'm not looking at every one else's errors.

I can do this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_log','path/to/mylogfile.log');
```

And that works for some errors, but for actual syntax errors, the logs are still being sent to the master /var/log/httpd/error_log. How do I make the syntax errors get sent to my custom log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the file cannot be correctly parsed, the `ini_set` function is not executed either and neither is the new error log set. You need to set `php_value error_log /path/to/myfile.log` in an `.htaccess` file or the global server config (I'm assuming that you're using Apache).

Answer (score 1):

Given that syntax errors prevent PHP from running you will not be able to set log paths via PHP. It's a chicken before the egg situation.

Alternatives would be:

- Change the error log at the webserver level
- Enable output of error messages to the browser

I'd suggest the latter.