# Why can't I get errors to write to a log file in PHP7

Tags: php, error-handling

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); // Error/Exception engine, always use E_ALL
ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors', FALSE); // always use TRUE
ini_set('display_errors', FALSE); // Error/Exception display, use FALSE only in production environment or real server. Use TRUE 

ini_set('log_errors', TRUE); // Error/Exception file logging engine.
ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/php_errors.log'); // Logging file path
echo ('test');
ehco('test');
?>
```

nothing being written to /tmp/php_error.log...
It's frustrating because even in the php.ini file is

> error_log = /tmp/php_errors.log

and the ls -al on /tmp

> -rwxrwxrwx   1 apache    staff          0 Mar 17 16:20 php_errors.log

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717279/changing-where-php-logs-syntax-errors

Comment: Ok so I'm using the SLIM framework and that was ok however I still can't get logs from a 500 page unavaiable error